# Yii2 - custom validation with db query

Tags: yii2, yii2-validation

I am trying to make this custom validation works, but I am not getting anything at the moment. What seems to be the problem?

```
['password', function($attribute, $params){

                $password = \Yii::$app->db
                    ->createCommand("SELECT * FROM forbiddenPasswords WHERE password = '{$params}'")
                    ->queryOne();

                if($password)
                    $this->addError($attribute, 'This password is forbidden. Please try another.');
            }],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `$params` contains validator parameters, not attribute,
- you should correctly bind parameter in your query.

e.g. :

```
$count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forbiddenPasswords WHERE password = :password')
    ->bindValue(':password', $this->password)
    ->queryScalar();

if($count)
    $this->addError($attribute, 'This password is forbidden. Please try another.');
```

Or you could create an `ActiveRecord` model for `forbiddenPasswords` and use [`unique`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#unique) validator to do the same...

Answer (score 0):

I have checked that {$params} variable is for additional values. And if you want to validate password  assign the value like this.

```
 ['password', function($attribute, $params){

           $pass=$this->password;
            $password = \Yii::$app->db
                ->createCommand("SELECT * FROM forbiddenPasswords WHERE password = '{$pass}'")
                ->queryOne();

            if($password)
                $this->addError($attribute, 'This password is forbidden. Please try another.');
        }],
```

Answer (score 0):

## Don't write open password validator. It's unsecure!

In Yii2 you can use `validatePassword` method of [Security](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-security.html#validatePassword()-detail) component.

First store in database hash of password by `setPassword` method:

```
/**
 *
 * @param string $password WARNING! OPEN PASSWORD!
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
}
```

In model you should have method `validatePassword`:

```
/**
 * @param string $password WARNING! OPEN PASSWORD!
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function validatePassword($password)
{
    return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
}
```

Or, if you want use `User` model as form you can write this:

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        ['password', 'validatePassword']
    ];
}

/**
 * @param string $attribute attribute name
 * @param array $params Additional params
 */
public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
{
    if (Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($this->$attribute, $this->password_hash) == false) {
        $this->addError($attribute, Yii::t('frontend', 'Incorrect password'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, the question is not really about password hash.

Comment: @soju Unencrypted passwords does not bother you?

Comment: where do you see unencrypted passwords (except in forbiddenPasswords table, but it is not a problem) ??

Comment: @soju You are right. It's my paranoia. I hope under the `password` means `hashed password`.

Comment: Don't worry, it is good thing to be paranoiac when you are a web dev :)

Comment: @Onedev.Link I'll share you a secret some huge IT companies storing passwords unhashed. And `password` here unencrypted, since it just came from `POST`. And yea paranoia is good sometimes.

Comment: I have a table of forbidden passwords. I don't see a point of hashing something that is public (I am using twitter and dropbox list for this). 
This table is not connected to the user in any way. User password is hashed. User is not allowed to use a password found in the table, that's all.